# Count largest number of consecutive zeros in a vector using a vectorized function

Tags: r, vectorization

I'd like to build a function that takes a vector as an argument and returns the largest number of consecutive zeros. For instance:

```
a <- c(0,0,1,1,0)
b <- c(0,1,3,10,0,0,0)
x <- count_max_consecutive_zeros(a)
y <- count_max_consecutive_zeros(b)
```

Should result in x=2 and y=3. I could go for the obvious solution and make a loop:

```
count_max_consecutive_zeros <- function(x) {
  max_count <- 0
  current_count <- 0
  for (i in 1:length(x) {
   if(x[i] == 0) {
     current_count = current_count + 1
  } else {
    if(current_count > max_count) {
      max_count <- current_count
    }
    current_count <- 0
  }
}
```

This solution is fine for short vectors, however I'll have to use this function thousands of times on vectors that are tens of thousands of entries long, so I'm afraid I'll run into performance issues. Is there a vectorized function equivalent to `count_max_consecutive_zeros`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rle` and `max` to *count largest number of consecutive zeros*.

```
x <- rle(a==0)
max(x$lengths[x$values == TRUE])
#[1] 2
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

An option with `rleid`

```
library(data.table)
max(tapply(a[a==0], rleid(a)[a == 0], FUN = length))
#[1] 2
```

Comment: Definitely a nice option but I wouldn't like to add one more dependecy. I think I'll stick to @GKi's solution